# Ajax call returning empty data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I send an ajax call on the following URL and just echoing the response but unable to see in success function. 
Where am i wrong ?

html file

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{$PLUG_DIR}/cb_memcached/admin/ajax.php',
   data: {
      mode: 'videos'
   },
   type: 'post',

   success: function(xhr) {

    alert(xhr);
   }
});
```

php file

```
<?php 
echo "asasas";
?>
```

Comment: add `dataType:'text',` to ajax

Comment: ***{$PLUG_DIR}*** this is wrong. method should be ***post***

Comment: @guradio, default value of dataType is text :)

Comment: Tip: press F12 in your browser -> go to network tab -> see what's wrong

Comment: @RaviHirani i am using smarty. it's a plugin directory path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems OK. Please double check your URL. Hit your URL from browser to see response. This issue is only because of your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be some where in {$PLUG_DIR}. Still Call error and complete function to debug it.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{$PLUG_DIR}/cb_memcached/admin/ajax.php',
   data: {
      mode: 'videos'
   },
   type: 'post',

   success: function(xhr) {

    alert(xhr);
   },
   error: function(error) {

    alert(error);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data structure :

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{$PLUG_DIR}/cb_memcached/admin/ajax.php',
    data: {
        mode: 'videos'
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(xhr) {
        var param1 = xhr.param1;
        alert(param1);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    $response["param1"] = "param1";
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please check below scenarios:

1. Make sure you include jquery plugin.
2. URL path should be correct.(In your case this may be wrong)
3. To check the error from ajax call please open inspect element from  chrome and check the response in network tab.